# Relative Imports for two parents dir up

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror, pythonpath, python-packaging

I have the following directory structure

```
code
|-----|--experiments
|        |---v0
|            |---agcnn.py
|-----|--pn
|        |---bag
|            |--run.py
```

`run.py` uses a module inside the `agcnn.py`. However when I try the import as following:

```
from experiments.v0.agccn import AG
```

it gives a relative import error saying no module. I'm using VScode and the the working dir is taken care by Vscode as root which is `/code/` in this case. 
How can I change the settings to accommodate the import ?

Comment: Is there a difference if you run `python pn/bag/run.py` or `python -m pn.bag.run`?